# Spring Injection can not find variable in resource file

Tags: spring, configuration, resource-files

I have a resource file created in my project. I want to inject values from resource file into spring bean. i defined the place holder for resource file in the applicacationContext.xml.

```
<context:property-placeholder  location="file:///${MRAPOR_PROPPATH}mRapor.properties" />
```

I can inject values to beans which is declared in the applicationContext.xml like :

```
<bean
        id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" >

        <property
            name="jndiName"
            value="${database.jndiName}" />

        <property
            name="lookupOnStartup"
            value="false" />

        <property
            name="cache"
            value="true" />

        <property
            name="proxyInterface"
            value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
    </bean>
```

This works well. However, i can not inject values if i declare beans with spring annotations.

```
@Component("SecurityFilter")
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter {
    public static final String USER = "USER_SESSION_KEY";
    public static final String CENTRIFY_USERNAME_KEY = "REMOTE_USERNAME";

    @Value("${url.logout}")//I get error here !!!!
    private String logoutUrl;
    //proper setters and  getters.
}
```

Do you have any idea why i can not access values inside the beans declared using annotations.

Here is my exception

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1510)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'url.logout' in string value [${url.logout}]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:173)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:255)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:748)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@Value` is processed by the java compiler whereas the the XML is parsed by Spring Bean Processor - these are two very different things... Why do you assume that should work in the same manner?

**Edit**: I read up on it and it seems to actually be possible using the Spring EL, you only have to prefix with `#` instead of `$`:

```
private @Value( "#{application.url.logout}" ) String logoutUrl;
```

Cheers,

Comment: i know the difference. however, i have already declared my resource file in application context. do you know any way to inject it via @Value annotation ?

Comment: See my edit and cf. Spring Expression Language: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html#new-feature-el

Comment: unfortunately. ı get "field or property not found" error. Spring tries to inject some a bean in the context. however, application.url.logout is not a spring bean.

Comment: Have you read the link - you need to provide the properties on the form `<util:properties id="application" location="classpath:your/package/your-application.properties"/>` - the `id="application"` prefix shall match your `@Value` annotation.

Comment: To elaborate, the `your-application.properties` should probably have a line like `url.logout=/.../logout.do`

Comment: exactly, i have an entry named url.logout=.... I use context:property-placeholder tag to read properties file instead util:property. i replaced property:placeholder with util:property. the same still doen not work.

Comment: It would help if you copied the entire stack trace for us to see, also could you try changing `url.logout` to `url_logout` both in the property file and the annotation?

Comment: OK, I'm almost out of ideas here... The error suggests that it is the `application` that isn't found, but if you use `<property-placeholder...` I would expect that the annotation should just be `@Value( "url.logout" )` provided that is what's in your property file before the `=` sign.

Comment: Sorry for that. i updated my codes accordingly. i still have error. ı Think the reason of the error is the filter itself since i declare it in web.xml. the servlet container loaded before spring container which means that there is no property file in the environment. just an idea. if so. ı really do not know if i can solve the problem.

Comment: That sounds very plausible - have a look at this article then: http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/20/bootstraping-a-web-application-with-spring-3-1-and-java-based-configuration-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the instance of `SecurityFilter` that actually filters requests is managed by Spring?

By default `Filter`s declared in `web.xml` are instantiated by servlet container, therefore they are not managed by Spring and Spring annotations such as `@Value` won't work in them.

However, Spring provides special support for your use case - you can delegate filtering to a component managed by Spring using `DelegatingFilterProxy`. Declare it in `web.xml` as follows:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>...</filter-mapping>
```

`DelegatingFilterProxy` will delegate request filtering to a bean named `SecurityFilter` (as in your `@Component`).

Comment: Yes, i have a delegating filter entry as you suggest in my web.xml. so my security filter is managed by Spring.